# How to create a bridge device to be used with virt-manager,that I have installed within ubuntu 22.10,installed on the WSL2 system on Windows 11

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, bridge, wsl2

I've just installed virt-manager on my Ubuntu 22.10 that I've installed within the WSL2 system running on Windows 11 with the aim to virtualize FreeBSD. I've reaized that virt-manager didn't create any bridge device so I can't assign it to the FreeBSD vm that I'm creating,as you can see :

[image: 1]

Do you have some straight documentation that I can study to learn the process to create the missing bridge adapter ? I've found some documentation,but due to the recent changes made by Microsoft to the WSL2,I'm not sure about which method found on internet is the good one. I don't want to break the hard work that I did until now to make work everything correctly. So I don't wat to experiment,I want to go directly to the right steps to perform to reach the result I want. Thank you.

NAT is also inactive and I'm not able to enable it :

```
root@marietto-windows11:/mnt/c/Users/virtu/Downloads/cmder# virsh net-list --all
 Name      State      Autostart   Persistent
----------------------------------------------
 default   inactive   yes         yes

root@marietto-windows11:/mnt/c/Users/virtu/Downloads/cmder# sudo virsh net-start default

error: Failed to start network default

error: internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /usr/sbin/iptables -w --table nat --insert POSTROUTING --jump LIBVIRT_PRT: iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables):  CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain POSTROUTING
```